# ATmega48PA: can not run PWM on OC0A and OC2A pins

Tags: avr, pwm, atmega, timer

I have some troubles trying to run Fast PWM on OC0A and OC2A pins.

The code is the following:

```
TCNT0 = 0;
TCNT2 = 76/2;
OCR0B = 76;
OCR2B = 76;
OCR0A = 10;
OCR2A = 10;
TCCR0A = 0b11000011;
TCCR2A = 0b10000011;
TCCR0B = 0b1010;
TCCR2B = 0b1010;
```

So I assume that timers will run with 1:8 speed from 0 (and 38 for Timer 2) to the top defined by OCRxB registers (76) and will change pins state on TOP (76) and OCRxA (10).

That's not work: the pins OC0A and OC2A connecting to the timers (as I can not change their state by putting 1 and 0 into respecting PORTD and PORTB bits) but there is no PWM signal.

However if I try to use OC0**B** and OC2**B** pins - everything works:

```
TCNT0 = 0;
TCNT2 = 76/2;
OCR0A = 76;
OCR2A = 76;
OCR0B = 10;
OCR2B = 10;
TCCR0A = 0b00110011;
TCCR2A = 0b00100011;
TCCR0B = 0b1010;
TCCR2B = 0b1010;
```

Need to note that in this case OC0A and OC2A pins can be driven directly by changing the pin state (which proofs that I don't have any schematic flaws).

I tried to replace the values of OCRxA and OCRxB in first code but that didn't help:

```
TCNT0 = 0;
TCNT2 = 76/2;
OCR0A = 76;
OCR2A = 76;
OCR0B = 10;
OCR2B = 10;
TCCR0A = 0b11000011;
TCCR2A = 0b10000011;
TCCR0B = 0b1010;
TCCR2B = 0b1010;
```

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 1**

Sorry for omitting part of the code. The ports definitions goes before the main code:

```
DDRB =  0b00001010;
PORTB = 0b11110101;
DDRC =   0b0000000;
PORTC =  0b1111110;
DDRD =  0b01101000;
PORTD = 0b10010011;
```

Comment: Where are you setting your ports? DDRA and DDRD?

Comment: Hi, @Hayman! I ommited this part. I just put it in UPDATE 1. Please F5 the post!

Comment: OC2A Uses port B data bit 3, which you have set to 0, this needs to be set as an output. OC0B and OC2B are data bits 3 and 5 on port D which you have set to 1 which explains why they're working fine

Comment: @Hayman DDRB.3 is set to one: DDRB =  0b0000**1**010;

Comment: Sorry you're right that's my mistake. However I still believe that the error lies in the definitions as you've changed the main code and checked your circuit.

Comment: @Hayman, please note that I can control those pins with PORTD.6 and PORTB.3 bits (if COMxA1 = COMxA0 = 0). So schematic should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news for me:

*'You will not get a useful PWM on the OCnA pin on an AVR8 if you select a mode that has OCRnA as TOP.  As you have found, you can use OCR0A as TOP and OCR0B for the duty and output on OC0B.  Or use a mode with a fixed TOP, and then you can get PWM on both OC pins.'*

This I received on [AVRFreaks forum](http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/1832451#comment-1832451) from a member.

So it looks like I will not be able to configure the PWM to work on OCxA pins with OCxA registers as a TOP value. :(((